# How to merge multiple responses into one json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cheerio

How to merge multiple responses into one json? Thanks!

When i run the code i get error:

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

....

```
var trackArrayReg = [
/^[A-Z]{2}\d{14}NPI$|^460\d{9}$|^959\d{9}$/i,
/^LP0\d{13}$|^[A-Z]{2}\d{14}NPI$/i
];

router.get('/:trackId', function(req, res) {
var trackId = req.params.trackId;

trackArrayReg.forEach(function(item, index, urlsArray) {
    if (trackArrayReg[index].exec(trackId)) {
        track = index;

        request({
            method: config[track].method,
            url: config[track].url + trackId,
            timeout: config[track].timeout,
            maxAttempts: 3,
            retryDelay: 500
        }, function(err, response, body, callback) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);

            $ = cheerio.load(body);

            stat = [];


            $(config[track].response.rowSelector).map(function(i, links) {
                var date = $(links).find(config[track].response.columnSelector).eq(config[track].response.dateColumnIndex).text(),
                    status = $(links).find(config[track].response.columnSelector).eq(config[track].response.stateColumnIndex).text(),
                    location = $(links).find(config[track].response.columnSelector).eq(config[track].response.locationColumnIndex).text();
                stat.push({
                    location: location,
                    date: date,
                    status: status,
                    carrier: track
                });
            });

            var states = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stat));

            res.send({states});
          });}});});
```

....

Comment: Assuming your multiple responses are in json format, you can use jQuery $.merge() in a repeating function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the incoming request is firing off multiple external requests which are parsed for some stat information that is ultimately meant to be combined and then included in the response to the original incoming request. If that is accurate then this is an issue with handling multiple asynchronous requests.

How to address the issue requires us to look at what is currently happening. Since the external requests are all asynchronous calls that are effectively fired off in parallel by the `forEach` loop, then whichever request responds first will be the one that fires off the response to the original incoming request. Unfortunately the remaining external requests will also try to respond to the original incoming request once they receive a response themselves. Hence the error from Express about trying to respond more than once.

Effectively the code is currently doing this (assuming `x > y`):

```
incoming req --> external req #1 (t0) --> response (t0+x) --> res.send ❌
             --> external req #2 (t0) --> response (t0+y) --> res.send ✅
```

*Note: The external requests are in a race condition so whichever one receives a response first will respond first to the original incoming request.*

To get around this issue there needs to be a way to manage the asynchronous external requests and then to combine their outputs.

Addressing the first part of the solution, managing the asynchronous requests, can be handled by using promises. Since `request` is already being used in the code then it is a simple switch to using the promise version: [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise). *Note: we can also make use of the `transform` function from `request-promise` to simplify the body parsing via `cheerio`.*

The next part is to combine the parsed responses from the external requests.

Currently the code as described above is firing off a bunch of requests in parallel. Assuming that is not an issue, we can use `Promise.all` with a 'map', rather than the `forEach`, to wait for all of the requests to respond.

*Note: Given each request appears to create an array of values, the overall result would be an array of those arrays of values.*

So in our flow diagram we would have:

```
inc req --> p.all(map(ext req #1 (t0) --> res (t0+2n) -->)) --> res.send ✅
                     (ext req #2 (t0) --> res (t0+n)  -->)
```

Putting it all together (with some other syntax edits):
*Note: this is untested code.*

```js
const requestPromise = require('request-promise-native');
const trackArrayReg = [
  /^[A-Z]{2}\d{14}NPI$|^460\d{9}$|^959\d{9}$/i,
  /^LP0\d{13}$|^[A-Z]{2}\d{14}NPI$/i
];

router.get('/:trackId', ({params: {trackId}}, res) => {
  Promise.all(trackArrayReg.map((regexp, track) => {
    if (regexp.test(trackId)) {
      return requestPromise({
        method: config[track].method,
        url: config[track].url + trackId,
        timeout: config[track].timeout,
        maxAttempts: 3,
        retryDelay: 500,
        transform(body) {
          return cheerio.load(body);
        }
      }).then(($) => {
        const rows = $(config[track].response.rowSelector);

        return rows.map((links) => {
          const columns = $(links).find(config[track].response.columnSelector);
          const date = columns.eq(config[track].response.dateColumnIndex).text();
          const status = columns.eq(config[track].response.stateColumnIndex).text();
          const location = columns.eq(config[track].response.locationColumnIndex).text();

          return {
            location,
            date,
            status,
            carrier: track
          };
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      });
    }
  })).then((stats) => {
    // Combine or modify the stats array as desired
    res.json(stats);
  });
});
```

For a further exercise in refactoring you could also use the syntactic sugar of async/await to help with managing the promises. I'll leave that as an exercise for the curious.

Hope this helps!